# Rxjs - map source observable and observables that modify it

Tags: functional-programming, rxjs

I would like to create an observable for `users` resource. I want to create it in a way that when I get events as `newUser` or `updateUser` my `users` array is updated accordingly.

```
const usersList = new Observable(USERS_ARRAY) // Returns list of users
const newUser = new Observable([NEW_USER, NEW_USER...]) // Returns value every time new user join

const users = Observable.combineLatest(usersList, newUser)
  .map(data => [...data[0], data[1]])
```

Does work only for the first `newUser` event because the output value isn't stored anywhere.

How can I do it properly with rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BehaviorSubject for this. A Subject implements the Observer and Observable interface, so you can listen to it and push data to it.

so you could try something like that

```
const usersList = new Observable(USERS_ARRAY) // Returns list of users
const newUser = new BehaviorSubject([NEW_USER, NEW_USER...]) // Returns value every time new user join

const users = Observable.combineLatest(usersList, newUser)
  .map(data => [...data[0], data[1]])

// when you want to add a new user
newUser.next(<your new NewUser Array>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan to store data and at the same time keep updating it.

```
let userArray=[user1,user2...]
newUser.scan((acc,curr)=>[...acc,curr],userArray)
.subscribe(console.log)
```